# Triangles incident on a vertex (Graphs)

Tags: terminology, graphs

I have a project that I am doing. The specification requires specific methods on a graph class. Two of the methods requires this:

> - `numberOfTrianglesIncidentToVertex()`, calculates and returns the number of triangles incident to vertex v. The algorithm below calculates the number of triangles incident for all graph vertices (V is the set of vertices, E is the set of edges):

```
foreach v in V
  foreach pair of vertices (p, q) in AdjacencyList(v)
    if (p, q) is in E then
      add 1 to triangles[v]
```

> - `listOfTrianglesIncidentToVertex()` calculates and returns the list of triangles incident to vertex v.  A triangle should be specified by its vertices.

I have no idea what a *triangle* is in regards to the vertex and graphs. Can someone give me a clear explanation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_graph

Answer (score 1):

A *triangle* is a set of three vertices `p`, `q`, `r`, from the graph where there is a graph edge between `p` and `q` (that is `q` is in `AdjacencyList(p)`), and there is a graph edge between `q` and `r` and there is a graph edge between `p` and `r`.